# How to find the derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$q = Q e^{-2t} (\cos t + 2 \sin t)$$

I've been stuck for days on these problems. By the answer I would assume there is a rule I am missing. I think I have all the rules for differentiation but none seem to apply. Is there a rule for this? If not, how do I find the answer?

Comment: You need the product rule for that.

Comment: You need to use several concepts: product rule, derivate of sum, derivative of $c \cdot f(t)$, derivatives of $\sin$ and $\cos$, and derivative of $e^{f(t)}$.

Comment: can you explain to me joe

Comment: Do you know the derivative of $\cos t$? or the derivative of $e^{-2t}$? You should show what you do know.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Presumably q is a function of t and Q is a constant. Is that correct?

Comment: yup we goo find a dq/dt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$q=Qe^{-2t} ( 2sin{t} + cost)=$$
$$2Qe^{-2t}sin{t} + Qe^{-2t}cost=$$
Differentiating $2Qe^{-2t}sin{t}$
$$ 2Q \biggl(\frac{d e^{-2t}}{dt}sint + \frac{dsint}{dt}e^{-2t} \biggr)=$$
$$ 2Q \biggl(\frac{d e^{-2t}}{d(-2t)}.\frac{d(-2t)}{dt}sint + \frac{dsint}{dt}e^{-2t} \biggr)=$$
$$ 2Q \biggl(-2e^{-2t}sint + cost e^{-2t} \biggr)$$

Differentiating $Qe^{-2t}cost=$
$$ Q \biggl(\frac{d e^{-2t}}{dt}cost + \frac{dcost}{dt}e^{-2t} \biggr)=$$
$$ Q \biggl(\frac{d e^{-2t}}{d(-2t)}.\frac{d(-2t)}{dt}cost + \frac{cost}{dt}e^{-2t} \biggr)=$$
$$ Q \biggl(-2e^{-2t}cost -sin(t) e^{-2t} \biggr)$$

Finally we get
$$-4Qe^{-2t}sint + 2Qcoste^{-2t} -2Qe^{-2t}cost -Qsin(t)e^{-2t}$$

$$-5Qe^{-2t}sint$$

Answer (score 1):

You want to differentiate $y= Qe^{-2t}(\cos(t)+ \sin(2t))$  As others have said, you need to know:

The sum rule: $(f+ g)'= f'+ g'$ with $f(t)= \cos(t)$, $g(t)= \sin(2t)$

The product rule: $(fg)'= f'g+ fg'$ with $f(t)= Qe^{-2t}$, $g(t)= \cos(t)+  \sin(2t)$

The fact that $(e^{-2t})'= -2e^{-2t}$

The fact that $(\cos(t))'= - \sin(t)$

The fact that $(\sin(2t))'= 2\cos(2t)$

Comment: In your last equation, it should be $...=2cos(2t))$

Comment: some MathJAX tips: put backslashes before sin and cos (i.e. `\sin` and `\cos`), and surround all of the math with `$` (like in your sum rule and product rule).